# Table with foreign key that can reference different tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to build a table for an inbox app that stores its messages within `inbox` table.

The structure of the table is as follows:

```
inbox_id|sender_id|receiver_id|subject|message
```

The columns `sender_id` and `receiver_id` are **FOREIGN KEYS** and can reference multiple tables.

There are currently 3 types of users within the database and they all can send messages to each other. A user of type `UserType1` can send a message to `UserType2` and vice versa, or `UserType1` can send messages to `UserType1`. So receiver and sender can reference one of these 3 tables.

My solution to this problem is to build a `inbox_user` table containing columns for each user type and to have `sender_id` and `inbox_user` reference it.

My main concern is limited flexibility of the solution and wasteful usage of resources. I would, at all times, always have 2 empty columns per row. And that would become even worse if I introduced more user types.

Would this be considered a bad practice? What are some more flexible and intelligent designs?

Comment: It depends which DB you use. If postgres, then there's no wasted space if the values are null.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan. None of the SQL platforms, or the freeware, waste space for nulls.  All of them take up 4 bytes.  Postgres has the largest row overhead.

Comment: (a) Yes, it is horrible practice. (b) *Inbox is actually a component of a larger app and therefore requires this, exact way of handling users* problem is bad design propagates itself, and restricts correct implementation, as in the next enhancement.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA PostgreSQL uses null bitmap, and takes far less than 4 bytes per NULL (and as little as one bit in ideal circumstances).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic.  So, the bitmap is in the row overhead. Six of one, or half a dozen of the other.  Anyway, the point is *None of the SQL platforms, or the freeware, waste space for nulls.* Not how the space is not wasted, or wasted elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like the best practice should be applied to your user table and not this inbox table. Of course, I don't know your constraints, but if you have 2 or 3 types of users with each type of user in its own table, that is a poor design (again, not knowing your constraints). The preference is to store all users in one table with a column to indicate their type. Then the reference to your inbox table becomes straightforward with both sender and receiver FKs pointing back to the same user table.

Otherwise, you're going to end up using multiple columns to reference each table like you said (UserTypeASenderID, UserTypeBSenderID, UserTypeCSenderID, etc). My preference is to have null FK columns and gain the referential integrity than to implement some other solution and lose the constraints.

Comment: I should have been more specific. Inbox is actually a component of a larger app and therefore requires this, exact way of handling users.

Comment: Big up-tick re "poor design". Big-down tick for Nullable columns.

Comment: Just trying to make the best of a bad situation.

Comment: Sure.  But you state it as a preference.

Comment: The larger app requires *what* way of handling users? Do you see your problem residing in the inbox table or the 3 user tables? What exactly do you see as the problem? You state your main concern is wasted space (too trivial to regard as a problem) and limited flexibility (while implying you are stuck with the design you have). What are you expecting a solution to solve?

Comment: @TommCatt, Actually, I think Jax's solution is much more elegant than what I thought of. I'm really just a beginner and am learning about DB designs for a personal project that I'm working on.

Comment: Jax didn't present a solution. He pointed out the fact that using three different user tables to represent three different types of users is a Bad Idea. And he is correct. My comment was aimed more at you, to try to get you to expand a bit on your problem and what you are looking for as a solution. You seemed to indicate that you are stuck with the design you have so any solution involving changing the tables would not work. Is that true? We need to know so we don't waste time redesigning your schema.

Answer (score 1):

3 different types of users is a classic type/subtype situation.  (or, if you prefer, class/subclass).  There are several ways to design for a class/subclass situation.  Two that look good to me are "Class Table Inheritance" and "Single Table Inheritance" as explained by Martin fowler.  You can find a synopsis online.  You can also visit tags by these names in here, read up on the info presented, and look at the tagged questions.

Single table inheritance suffers from a lot of NULLs for fields that are not applicable some of the time, as you pointed out in the Q.  This may or may not be a problem for you, depending on your case.

Class table inheritance involves a little programming when a new entry is made in a subclass (subtype).  It also involves more joining, but it isn't very expensive joining.  Class table inheritance is frequently combined with a technique called shared primary key.  In this technique, the subclass tables end up with a primary key that is a duplicate of the primary key in the superclass table.  It's also a foreign key to the superclass table.  This makes joining subclass data and superclass data simple, easy, and fast.

Shared primary key resolves the quandary you stated in your Q, namely how to reference more than one table with one foreign key.  A foreign key reference in some other table to the superclass table will also be a reference to at least one of the subclass tables.  This seems like magic.  Try it, see if you like it.